# Solution to a PDE that requires fundamental Laplace solutions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, laplacian, fundamental-solution

I would like to derive the spherical symmetric solutions (or in another words make use of the fundamental solutions) of the following PDE:

\begin{equation}
\Delta u(x)+\lambda u(x)=0, \quad \lambda>0, \quad x\in \mathbb{R}
^2
\end{equation}

I know how to solve for the fundamental solutions of the Laplace equation:
\begin{equation}
\Delta u(x)=0
\end{equation}
but I am not sure how to proceed with the other one. 
Thank you for your time!

Comment: It's a Helmholtz equation. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_equation

Comment: So there are no specific solutions that I can derive by making use of the fundamental laplace solutions?

Comment: Using eigensystem you may, using fundamental solution I doubt